# Bar chart displaying too few days

Tags: windows-7, charts, microsoft-project-2013

I am trying to display a week-long step in a project. I am using the standard calendar. 8 hours per day, 40 hours per week, 31 days per month. Auto schedule. The "Days" column shows the correct number of days. The "Start" and "Finish" columns show the correct dates, Monday and Friday respectively. Unfortunately, the bar chart shows the step starting on Tuesday and finishing on Friday, only four days. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by "bar chart" you are referring to the Gantt chart view?  Turn on the display of time (File>Options, General).  What time does the task start on Monday?
Right click in the Gantt chart and choose Layout - turn off the "round bars to whole days".